# For Each Key Isn't A Number

Tags: php, xml, pagination

So I'm trying to iterate through an XML feed and paginate it but I've run into a problem. When I try to get the index (key) of the current array it outputs a string "campDetails" on every iteration instead of an incrementing integer like 0,1,2,3

Here is a sample of the XML format

> ```
> <campaigns>
> <campDetails>
> <campaign_id>2001</campaign_id>
> <campaign_name>Video Chat Software</campaign_name>
> <url>http://www.fakeurl.com</url>
> </campDetails>
> ```

```
<?php
 $call_url = "https://www.fakeurl.com";
  if($xml = simplexml_load_file($call_url, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA)):

           foreach($xml as $i => $offers):
                $offer_link     = $offers->url;
                $offer_raw_name = $offers->campaign_name;
              echo $i . " " . $offer_link; ?> </br> <?php echo $offer_raw_name;
           endforeach;
  endif;
  ?>
```

Output to be expected:

```
0 http://www.fakeurl.com
Video Chat Software
```

Actual output:

```
campDetails http://www.fakeurl.com
Video Chat Software
```

EDIT: Thank you for your answers everyone. It seems I was given incorrect information from another question on here. I was told that $i would keep a numerical index for the current iteration.

print_r($xml); (obviously more results but this is the first)

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [campDetails] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [campaign_id] => 2001 [campaign_name] => Video Chat Software [url] => http://www.fakeurl.com/ )
```

Comment: `$xml` isn't a numerical indexed array, if that's what you were expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the current foreach and associative array, I pushed all values to an indexed array.

Answer (score 0):

In this usage of `foreach`, `$i` is not a *numeric* index but a *key*. In this case, the key for the current object is `campDetails`.

**Alternative Code**

```
$i = 0;
foreach($xml as $offer) {
    // your code...
    ++$i;
}
```

For more details on the type of object you receive from `simplexml_load` [read the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) or debug with `print_r($xml);`.

Comment: Will this still be viable since I'm using it for pagination?

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you modify your code with the code I provided, it will achieve your desired output.

Comment: The output is not so much I am concerned about. I am concerned about having a numerical index to go with the current array iteration.
From there I can set a starting point and an end point for my pagination.

For example: If ($_GET['page'] == 1): start displaying xml from index 1 to 10.

Comment: Add `print_r($xml);` to your code and update your question with the output.

Comment: It's difficult to tell exactly without seeing the entire `$xml` object. Nonetheless, I believe you are looping over the wrong object in order to achieve what you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19128/discussion-between-query-and-jason-mccreary)

Answer (score 0):

Your `$i` is not an index. You could do something like:

```
$index = 0;
foreach($xml as $i => $offers):
    $offer_link     = $offers->url;
    $offer_raw_name = $offers->campaign_name;
    echo $index++ . " " . $offer_link; ?> </br> <?php echo $offer_raw_name;
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

`simplexml_load_file` returns an object, a `foreach` loop will iterate over its fields, and `$i` will hold the current field's key.

If you want a numeric counter as well, just increment on your own:

```
$j = 0;
foreach($xml as $i => $offer){

    // do your stuff
    $j++;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit redundant, but you can use something like:

```
$x = 0;
foreach($xml as $i => $offers):
    // other stuff
    echo $x . " " . $offer_link; ?> </br> <?php echo $offer_raw_name;
    $x++;
endforeach;
```

You can also streamline your echo line like so:

```
echo "$i $offer_link <br> $offer_raw_name";
```